# Xcode 4 Icon Problem !

Tags: ios, ios4, xcode4

My problem is:

```
Icon specified in the Info.plist not found under the top level app wrapper: Icon.png (-19007)
```

I've done exactly what Apple documentation says and I'm still getting this warning!
I have everything set, everything is in PNG, the size is correct, Info.plist has added Icon files with 6 items (Icon.png, Icon@2x.png, Icon-72.png, Icon-Small-50.png, Icon-Small.png, Icon-Small@2x.png)

I have tried all the ways which I found in different website but none of these solution work for me.

Anyone please help me? I didn't get this warning while I'm doing Debug build but this comes out when I'm doing Distribution build.

Previously I never encounter this problem.

Comment: Hi, I have the same trouble.
When you ckeck your build (Open with Finder on X.app) then show the contents of the package of the archive you'll see that your Icon.png was renamed to icon.png
This is the problem, but I don't know how to fix it...

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that your icon is in the root of your project. Or you can select the app icon you want to use from the target's summary tab and Xcode will automatically copy the selected icon to the root of the project.
[image]

Comment: Up until this week I never had any problems with this and then I tried to submit an update for one of my existing apps and ran into this problem. I'm not sure why the change happened, but thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had iphone and ipad icon.
First I removed ipad target.
I solved it, editing info.plist file manually and deleting no existing reference.
All very simple and quick, but difficult to find the solution.