# App icon doesn't appear

Tags: ios

I followed [these instructions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html) to add my app's icon. Specifically, I created a `png` named `Icon.png`, I added the following items to my AppName-Info.plist file, and I cleaned the project. Yet I still see the default icon Apple provides.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999586/xcode-4-icon-problem?rq=1) and see if the answer provided helps you.

Comment: I'm not sure it is required, but in my project all the files are listed there with the ".png" extension

Comment: @RosePerrone Would have been helpful if you mentioned that you were using asset catalogs or Xcode 5 in the initial question. Xcode 5 is in Beta and is not assumed to be the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rose - That looks ok. Couple places to look/items to try:

1. You did in fact copy all of the icon files into your project as well, correct?
2. Try removing these entries from your plist and adding them in by dragging the icons to the App icons area on your Target > Summary page.

Comment: It turns out I needed to add the images to the "AppIcon" entry in Images.xcasset

Answer (score 2):

Xcode may have forgotten to add them to your Bundle Resources.  Got to your project settings -> Targets -> Build Phase -> expand Copy Bundle Resources.

If you don't see all the Icon png files in there, drag them from your Project Navigator on the left to the Copy Bundle Resources window.  It should work after doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Might also want to check if they exist in the project directory, and if they don't show up in xcode, go to File>Add Files to "Your Project" and make sure the Copy items is checked. Otherwise, just a breakable link will map the asset to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the app, then close the simulator and run the app again.
That worked for me.